# How to find common numbers in two vectors of different sizes

Tags: c++, stl

I have two integer vectors of different sizes:

vector 1 = {1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8}

vector 2 = {1, 3, 3, 5, 8}

I am trying to loop through both of these vectors and compare there values to see if they are similar then add them to a new vector.

Here is what I have tried:

```
vector<int> firstList{1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8}
vector<int> secondList{1, 3, 3, 5, 8}
vector<int> finalList;

    for (std::vector<char>::iterator i = firstList.begin(); i != firstList.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (std::find(secondList.begin(), secondList.end(), *i) != secondList.end())
        {
            finalList.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
```

The output I expect in the finalList is: {1, 3, 3, 5, 8}

The actual output is: {1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8} it returns 10 values when I only need 5.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What stops you from saving your current output in a new vector, and then remove all duplicate values from that vector, as an additional step? P.S. This entire approach is really wrong, and there are better ways to do this: 1) remove all duplicate values from both arrays, 2) combine the two arrays and sort the combined array 3) find all duplicate numbers in the new array, mission accomplished.

Comment: Instead of vector, use a [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: you can put your second array in the first loop and vise versa, then add a break after push_back(); it will give you the desired result, but it is not the correct answer to the problem because it will not work in all cases

Comment: when you found an item in the 2nd list, remove that item in the 2nd list so it will be excluded in find().

Comment: Solved it with set_intersection, thanks! @O'Neil

Answer (score 1):

make a copy of the smallest list and then remove found item on that list so on the next loop that found item will be excluded.

```
vector<int> firstList{1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8}
vector<int> secondList{1, 3, 3, 5, 8}
vector<int> finalList;

vector<int> secondListCopy = secondList;

for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = firstList.begin(); i != firstList.end(); ++i)
{
    std::vector<int>::iterator i2 = std::find(secondListCopy.begin(), secondListCopy.end(), *i) ;
    if (i2 != secondListCopy.end())
    {
        finalList.push_back(*i);
        secondListCopy.erase(i2);

        if(secondListCopy.empty()) break; //just additional optimization.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`. Initialize set with the largest vector.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<int> firstList{1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8};
vector<int> secondList{1, 3, 3, 5, 8};
vector<int> finalList;

set<int> firstSet{firstList.begin(),firstList.end()};
for(auto& i : secondList)
    if(*firstSet.find(i)) //find i in firstSet/firstList
       finalList.push_back(i);


for(auto& i : finalList)
   cout << i << " ";  //Output: 1 3 3 5 8 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this in O(NlogN) is to sort both the vectors and loop both of them at the same time.

```
sort(firstList.begin(),firstList.end());
sort(secondList.begin(),secondList.end());
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < firstList.size() && j < secondList.size())
{
    if (firstList[i] == secondList[j])
    {
        finalList.push_back(firstList[i]);
        i++;j++;
    }
    else if (firstList[i] < secondList[j])
    {
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```